# Is the ball live or dead when it bounces off a downed player's helmet?

Tags: rules, american-football, collegiate

In college football, is the ball considered live or dead if it hasn’t hit the ground but bounces off the helmet of a downed player?

Answer (score 2):

Is this in the context of a forward pass, or just a loose ball?  Either way it shouldn't matter (and for a loose ball, even hitting the ground shouldn't matter).  The ball should remain live.

Per the [NCAA 2022 rule book](https://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/FR22.pdf), conditions where the ball becomes dead is covered by Rule 4, Section 1, Article 3, "Ball Declared Dead".  That contains 18 separate points that cause a dead ball to occur.  None of them relate to touching a player (except that item "a" (out of bounds), is later defined to be possible as touching an out-of-bounds player).

All the other dead ball scenarios involving a player refer only to the ball carrier.  Touching some other player does not create a dead ball.

If this is a forward pass, touching a player but not the ground does not make it incomplete (item "i".  See also 7-3-7-a for rules of an incomplete pass).

If this is a fumble, then normally the ball must be recovered by a player or go out of bounds before becoming dead.